# $.inArray() is not giving exact index of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array.

```
var arr =[23,45,78,89];
```

I want to delete 78 from this array so i am using

```
 arr.splice($.inArray(78), 1);
```

but this always remove last element 89.

Plz help .

Comment: You are not passing array into splice.try like "arr.splice($.inArray(78,arr),1)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `arr` to [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
$.inArray(78, arr)
```

You should also verify that the value was found before splicing:

```
var index = $.inArray(78, arr);
if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

`splice` will treat the `-1` to mean "1st from end" (or "last").

Comment: hi jonathan this code is working on some function but sometime it is not working. Canyou suggest some other method to remove from array desired index element

Comment: @vikas Do you have an example of when it's "*not working*?" A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), perhaps? Taking a guess: `inArray` won't work the same with objects as it does with primitives, as objects are compared by reference rather than similarity (they have to be the exact same reference to "equal"). [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) can be [useful in those cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758986/15031).

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the second argument to `$.inArray` - try this:

```
arr.splice($.inArray(78,arr), 1);
```