# search 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've look at a few other posts but am still slightly confused about using arrays within arrays.

So I've created my array as below:

```
var pagesArray = [
    {
        category: 'pages1',
        pages: [
            'firstPage1',
            'secondPage1',
            'thirdPage1',
            'fourthPage1'
        ]
    }, {
        category: 'pages2',
        pages: [
            'firstPage2',
            'secondPage2',
            'thirdPage2',
            'fourthPage2'
        ]
    }
];
```

Now I want to be able to search the array and find if a string exists in it. If it does, I want it to return the value of what position it is.

E.g.

```
jQuery.inArray('secondPage1', pagesArray)
```

to give the result:

```
pagesArray[0][1];
```

I'm not sure if I've written the array wrong and if I'm using `inArray` correctly. If I try to `alert(pagesArray[0][1]);` it gives a value of undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can check the validity of your array by doing `console.log(pagesArray)`, then you know if the array is indeed correct.

Comment: `pagesArray[0][pages]` is what I think you'd need.

Comment: Please look here - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758937/using-jquery-inarray-with-array-of-javascript-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tB4TN/2/)

```
$.each(pagesArray, function (i, v) {
    if((pos=$.inArray('secondPage1', pagesArray[i]['pages'])) !== -1){
        console.log('pagesArray['+i+"]['pages']"+'['+pos+']');
    };
});
```

output `pagesArray[0]['pages'][1]`

`pagesArray[0]` means found in first array `[0]` `0` means first

`pagesArray[0]['pages'][1]` found in first array `[0]` inside sub array `['pages']` at index [`1`] Second position as index starts from 0

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tB4TN/1)

```
$.each(pagesArray, function (i, v) {
    if($.inArray('secondPage1', pagesArray[i]['pages']) !== -1){
        alert('inarray');
    };
});
```

to access category

```
console.log(pagesArray[1]['category']);
```

to access pages

```
console.log(pagesArray[1]['pages']);
```

to find values in array you can use

```
console.log($.inArray('secondPage1', pagesArray[0]['pages']));
```

Comment: This is great thanks. But Is there a way for it to tell me where it is in the array. For example if I search for secondPage1, I need it to tell me it's in the category pages1 and is the first item in that part of the array.

Comment: Aaah I've worked out how to do that last bit now. I can just return the 'i' value. Thanks for your help, this was a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pagesArray = [
    {
      category: 'pages1',
      pages: [
        'firstPage1',
        'secondPage1',
        'thirdPage1',
        'fourthPage1' ]
    }, {
      category: 'pages2',
      pages: [
        'firstPage2',
        'secondPage2',
        'thirdPage2',
        'fourthPage2' ]
    }
  ];

for(var i = 0; i < pagesArray.length; i++)
{
    var exist = jQuery.inArray("firstPage2", pagesArray[i]);
    if(exist)
    {
        alert('Got the Value!!!!');
        break;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/2xemE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function findInArray( arr, value ) {
   var j; 
   for ( var i in arr ) {
      if ( ~( j = arr[ i ].pages.indexOf( value ) ) )
         return { i: +i, j: +j };
   }
}

findInArray( pagesArray, 'thirdPage2' );
>> Object {i: 1, j: 2}
```

So it is `pagesArray[ 1 ].pages[ 2 ]`. Then:

```
var p = findInArray( pagesArray, 'thirdPage2' );
pagesArray[ p.i ].pages[ p.j ];
>> 'thirdPage2'
```

Accordingly you can write a method that returns the value or nothing to check whether an item exists:

```
function findInArray( arr, value ) {
   var j; 
   for ( var i in arr ) {
      if ( ~( j = arr[ i ].pages.indexOf( value ) ) )
         return arr[ i ].pages[ j ];
   }

   return false;
}

findInArray( pagesArray, 'foo ' );
>> false
findInArray( pagesArray, 'fourthPage2' );
>> 'fourthPage2'
```