# Is there an $.inArray function for objects / hashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something like this:

```
object = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 }
$.inObject(object, 'one') // returns true
$.inObject(object, 'three') // returns false
```

It would only search the keys.

Comment: Just use JavaScript: `object.hasOwnProperty('one')`

Comment: Here is a post that answers the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758937/using-jquery-inarray-with-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: `$.inArray` looks for values, whereas you seem to want to look for properties. Not sure which you actually want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The safest way to do this is using `.hasOwnProperty()`:

```
obj = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 };
obj.hasOwnProperty('one') // returns true
obj.hasOwnProperty('three') // returns false
```

You can also use the `in` operator as others have suggested like this:

```
obj = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 };
console.log('one' in obj)   // true
console.log('three' in obj) // false
```

But, the `in` operator can be confused by any properties on the prototype of the object that might have been added to Object by some library or other code so `hasOwnProperty()` is generally considered the safer option for detecting things you added to the actual object yourself.  In otherwords, if anyone added an method or property to the Object prototype, it would get picked up by the `in` operator, but not by `.hasOwnProperty()` which only checks the actual object itself, not any inherited properties.

---

FYI, this may be overkill for what you need for your particular use, but there's an implementation of a `Set` object and a `ValueSet` object that uses this type of logic and offers lots of typical `Set` operations  here: [Mimicking sets in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422).  The code is all available for the `Set` object too so you can see how it all works if you want to educate yourself further.

Comment: The clash with `in` isn't only with enumerable methods. Any property on the object or inherited will return `true`, irrespective of enumerability. However, this isn't necessarily less safe. Could be that in some cases inherited properties *should* be included.

Comment: @cookiemonster - in the OP's example, they clearly only want properties that they've defined themselves on the object to be included here and that is fairly typical which is why it is generally better to use `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: Just saying that it depends on the requirements. Still, whether a property is enumerable will have no impact on the result of the `in` operator. It isn't confused. It's just working as intended.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I've removed any mention of enumerability.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, the `in` keyword. No need to use jQuery:

```
object = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 };
alert('one' in object); // true
alert('three' in object); // false
```

You can also use `object.hasOwnProperty('blah')` which is more reliable. Douglas Crockford prefers this approach, you will find [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L412) complaining about this occassionally. I prefer the `in` notation as its easier to read.

Comment: "Strange results" with `.hasOwnProperty()`?  You mean `.hasOwnProperty()` will only return true if you actually added the property directly to the object yourself and not if some library you're using added it to the Object's prototype - which is what you usually want and what the OP appears to want.

Comment: This is a perfectly legit answer. Doesn't deserve downvotes, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `typeof`:

```
function inObject(obj, key) {
    return typeof obj[key] != "undefined";
}
```

Comment: you don't need typeof since accessing an object property that doesn't exists will give undefined . So you can use obj[key] !== undefined