# JQuery and Javascript to keep track of two players in one Associative Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am making a game of Simon, where two players play against both the AI and each other. To simplify things in the long run I'm rewriting a lot of code in order to keep everything in a single "player" array. However, I'm having trouble thinking of how I'm going to be able to keep track of certain things in the game, such as who's turn it is, or which object data goes into.

//both player1 and player2 are = $("#name").val() where #name is the input box entered and validated

```
    player[player.length] = {
        name: player1,
        points: 0,
        gamesWon: 0,
        gamesLost: 0,
        gamesTied: 0,
        sequence: null,
        correct: false
    };
    player[player.length] = {
        name: player2,
        points: 0,
        gamesWon: 0,
        gamesLost: 0,
        gamesTied: 0,
        sequence: null,
        correct: false
    };
```

This will be a growing array, where an indefinite amount of players are stored. For example, later on in my code, if I were to want to modify the second player's points, would I have to make a:

```
for(i=0; i < player.length; i++){if (player[i].name === $("#name").val()) {
```

//do stuff here;}}

Is there a simpler way of finding players and modifying that array position's values? Or finding whatever else I would need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `jQuery.grep( )` to search the array. Because you've got an array of objects, the `grep( )` function allows you to match on specific criteria, including properties of the object. This function returns the object you're looking for within the array, without affecting the original array. An example of usage:

```
var players = [];
player[0] = {
    name: player1,
    points: 0,
    gamesWon: 0,
    gamesLost: 0,
    gamesTied: 0,
    sequence: null,
    correct: false
};
player[1] = {
    name: player2,
    points: 0,
    gamesWon: 0,
    gamesLost: 0,
    gamesTied: 0,
    sequence: null,
    correct: false
};

$player2 = $.grep( player, function( p ) { p.name === "player2"; } ); //Returns the player2 object
```

Documentation on the `grep( )` function can be found at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/, and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758986/1245766) refers to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could index the players by both number and name.

```
var players = []

function joinGame(playerName) {
    var playerNumber = players.length;
    players[playerName] = {
        name: playerName,
        number: playerNumber
    };
    players[playerNumber] = players[playerName];
}

joinGame('player0');
joinGame('player1');

console.log('-- by player number --');
console.log(players[0]);
console.log(players[1]);

console.log('-- by player name --');
console.log(players['player0'])
console.log(players['player1']);

console.log('-- forEach on the array --');
players.forEach(function(p) {
    console.log(p);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85X3c/

Comment: But it still has an issue of me being able to capture data later on when many players are introduced. No? Say, at the end of each game, I have to update an existing player's "points" when that "name" already exists. Do you see my issue?

Comment: I was trying to do a separate variable at start, like player[player.length - 1] = person1 and player[player.length - 2] = person2 but that just adds complication in the long run. It wouldn't check if that "player" already exists.

Comment: I'm afraid then, I've misunderstood your problem. I thought you'd just want to modify `players[$("#name").val()]` and it would be an easy lookup for a player-by-name. I don't know what you're doing with `#name`, so I'm guessing, frankly.